# PHP what should I do if I want to echo table instead of foreach loops

Tags: php, html, mysql, foreach

I would like to ask how I should turn my foreach loops to a php code that echo the table content each by each?

Here is my .php

```
<?php
require_once  'init.php';

$articleQuery = $db->query("
SELECT 
articles.id, 
articles.title,
COUNT(articles_likes.id) AS likes,
GROUP_CONCAT(users.username SEPARATOR '|') AS liked_by

FROM articles

LEFT JOIN articles_likes
ON articles.id = articles_likes.article

LEFT JOIN users
ON articles_likes.user = users.id

GROUP BY articles.id
");

while($row = $articleQuery->fetch_object()){
$row->liked_by = $row->liked_by ? explode('|', $row->liked_by) : [];
$articles[] = $row;

}


$articleQuery = $db->query("
SELECT 
articles2.id, 
articles2.title,
COUNT(articles_dislikes.id) AS dislikes,
GROUP_CONCAT(users.username SEPARATOR '|') AS disliked_by

FROM articles2

LEFT JOIN articles_dislikes
ON articles2.id = articles_dislikes.article

LEFT JOIN users
ON articles_dislikes.user = users.id

GROUP BY articles2.id
");

while($row = $articleQuery->fetch_object()){
$row->disliked_by = $row->disliked_by ? explode('|', $row->disliked_by) 

: [];
$articles2[] = $row;

}

// echo '<pre>', print_r($articles, true), '</pre>';

?>
<?php foreach($articles as $article): ?>

<?php foreach($articles2 as $article1): ?>

<div class="article">
<h3><?php echo $article->title; ?></h3>
<a href="like.php?type=article&id=<?php echo $article->id; ?
>">Like<?php echo $article->likes; ?></a>


<div class="article1">
<a href="dislike.php?type=article&id=<?php echo $article1->id; 
?>">disLike<?php echo $article1->dislikes; ?></a>    



</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I want to echo the specific table title, id, and like for each html post,

Here is my table.sql

```
-- Table structure for table `articles`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `articles` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`title` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;


-- Dumping data for table `articles`
INSERT INTO `articles` (`id`, `title`) VALUES
(1, 'Test article one'),
(2, 'Test article two'),
(3, 'Test article three');

--------------------------------------------------------


-- Table structure for table `articles_likes`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `articles_likes` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`user` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`article` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `articles_likes`
--

INSERT INTO `articles_likes` (`id`, `user`, `article`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1),
(2, 1, 2),
(4, 2, 2);

--
-- Table structure for table `users`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`username` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;


-- Dumping data for table `users`
--

INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `username`) VALUES
(1, 'ifah'),
(2, 'alex');
```

It means when I made a article post in html, I want to echo let's say title 1 in h3 html thanks..

Comment: show some effort, try something then come ask for help.

Comment: can you add visual, on how you want your, output to be like.

Comment: Of course I can, thank you julekgwa. I acquired HTML and CSS only, never try the PHP, I will practise more so that one day I could help others back. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course I can, I want to thank you first for your answer. [sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9h4dx.png)

[sample likes count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AhHF.png)

So basically, I want to count the number of click in a post to serve as a like button, but when I want to echo them out, I only knew to use the loop to display.

I want to echo them one by one when I need them, like using button tag or div tag to echo them out. I am a college students with science background, I am trying hard to learn coding but not familiar with PHP. So tell me what you think. Thanks!!
  My table.sql

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `likebutton`
-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `articles`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `articles` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`title` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `articles`
--

INSERT INTO `articles` (`id`, `title`) VALUES
(1, 'Test article one'),
(2, 'Test article two'),
(3, 'Test article three');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

-- Table structure for table `articles_likes`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `articles_likes` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`user` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`article` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `articles_likes`
--

INSERT INTO `articles_likes` (`id`, `user`, `article`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1),
(2, 1, 2),
(4, 2, 2);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `users`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`username` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `users`
--

INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `username`) VALUES
(1, 'Anns'),
(2, 'Bob');
```

In addition, I want each id could only click once and can return to unlike the button. Thanks